# Let a and b be such that $-2A^2 + 4A -3I_2 = aA + bI_2$. To find $a + b$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification

$A \in M_2$ with characteristic polynomial $p(x) = x^2 -3x - 5$. Let a and b be such that  $-2A^2 + 4A -3I_2 = aA + bI_2$. To find $a + b$.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to simply apply the Cayley-Hamilton theorem here?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is correct. A simpler way to do it would be to use the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, i.e. the statement that each matrix satisfies its characteristic polynomial. From here, you can simply say that $A^2=3A+5$ and substitute this in.

Comment: There is a gap.  You obtain $-2A-13I=aA+bI$. That implies that $a=-2,b=-13$ only if $A$ is not a scalar matrix. This last point is true because $p(x)$ has two distinct roots.

Comment: @loupblanc Thanks for the note -- I didn't realize that needed to be taken into account.

Answer (score 2):

A matrix satisfies its characteristic polynomial.
$$-2A^2+4A-3I=aA+bI$$
$$-2A^2+(4-a)A+(-3-b)I=0$$
$$-2\left(A^2+\frac{a-4}{2}A+\frac{3+b}{2}I\right)=0$$
$$A^2+\frac{a-4}{2}A+\frac{3+b}{2}I=0$$
From this we need:
$$\frac{a-4}{2}=-3$$
$$a-4=-6$$
$$a=-2$$
and
$$\frac{3+b}{2}=-5$$
$$3+b=-10$$
$$b=-13$$
So $a+b=-15$

Comment: There is a gap. When you proceed to the identification of the polynomials, you must say that the roots of $p(x)$ are simple; that implies that $p(x)$ is also the minimal polynomial...

Comment: @loupblanc Doesn't Cayley–Hamilton theorem states that if $p(\lambda)=\det(A-\lambda I)$, then $p(A)=0?$

Comment: Of course; yet, if $p(x)=(x-u)^2$, then you may have $A=uI$ and $A^2=u^2 I$ and you cannot identify as you did.

Comment: @loupblanc Sorry, I don't get it. Won't the $A=uI$ satisfy the $p(A)=(A-uI)^2$ equation?

Comment: In these conditions, the polynomial that you obtain in line $5$ is a multiple of $x-u$; there is only one condition: it is $0$ when $x=u$.

Comment: @loupblanc Could you show the problem on an easy example, please?

Comment: Let $p(x)=(x-1)^2$. If $A=I$, then $-2A^2+4A-3I=-I=(a+b)I$; finally $a+b=-1$.

Comment: @loupblanc Ahh, I see now. Adding $2p$ to the given equation would result $-I=aA+bI$, and I would not be able to continue. Thank you!